Spotlighting a cell, and returning complete row in Google Sheets
I don't want to use app script function.  I need to target the last cell in Col1 that has a value in it and then return the data that is in the row that that cell is on.
I need to target ColA because every entry will have a timestamp in this column so there will be no blank cells.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kY6yOkCzXvpyFEM4wOn8ZbT4wmHntiZIk4qoZyMJzH8/edit?usp=sharing
Once I have a solution how do I adjust that formula so that I get the last 2 rows or the last 4 rows.
Important: the table isn't static.  It grows often by rows
I tried functions but felt like it was overkill.

the sheet is private. Please update the sharing settings to Anyone with the link > Editor

While a link to a spreadsheet might be helpful, questions should be self-contained. Please ensure that all the relevant details are included in the question.

Assuming the data is in A2:C
Last row
=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(A2:C,A2:A<>""),-1)

Last 2 rows
=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(A2:C,A2:A<>""),-2,-1)

Last n rows
=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(A2:C,A2:A<>""),-n,-n+1,-n+2,...,-1)

Or
=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(A2:C,A2:A<>""),SEQUENCE(n,1,-n))

